# Converting a direction vector to an angle

Tags: control-theory

I have a machine that controls its own velocity via the use of a fixed thruster mounted on its rear.

The machine knows its current velocity, and it knows the velocity it must attain. By subtracting the current from the target, it gets an error vector that represents how much it must alter its velocity for that velocity to match the target. The machine then negates that error vector and orients itself to the resulting direction vector, then applies thrust until the velocity vector is correct.

The trouble is, the part that controls the machine's orientation only accepts pitch-yaw-roll values. How do I calculate the angular values I need from the direction vector I have?

Comment: Is the machine moving in three dimensions, or two?  If three, is there any constraint on the allowed orientations?  (In general, if you specify the direction of the fixed thruster, that still leaves one degree of rotational freedom around that axis; so the pitch-yaw-roll values you're asking about are not unique.)

Comment: It's moving in three dimensional space. I'm not sure what you mean about constraint on allowed orientations. Wouldn't the roll value be irrelevant in this situation? No matter how the machine is rolled, the thruster will still be pointing the same way.

Comment: Right, that was my point… but if the roll axis is the thruster axis, then it's easy.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. The thruster is pointed so that however the machine is oriented, the thruster will be thrusting in the opposite direction, and the velocity vector will have (orientation*k) added to it every arbitrary amount of time, where orientation is the direction vector heading of the machine and k is how much delta-v the thruster can provide in that same arbitrary amount of time. So if you drew a line representing an imaginary axle that the machine turns around when it rolls, it would be parallel with the line representing the impulse the thruster applies.

Comment: I don't have a formal math education past basic algebra, so I'm trying to avoid the use of terms I'm not sure about the meaning of.

Comment: Euler angles perhaps? See Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles

Comment: For what it's worth, I've been pondering this for a while. My gut instinct is to look at a configuration space which is $SO(3)$, for which the yaw, roll, and pitch forms a natural chart. Since your system is furthermore fully actuated, the solution is likely given by computing a few Lie brackets and computing the optimal "direction" in $so(3)$ in which to travel. The solution will finally depend on the bounds on your control magnitudes: i.e. can you instantaneously affect your role/pitch/yaw? If not, your optimal control is not bang-bang and you must flow towards your trajectory.

Comment: Addendum: I suppose that more technically, your configuration space would be $SO(3) \times \mathbb R^3$.

Comment: I think your problem is very elementary, but you are using an engineering slang which is incomprehensible to many of us. My suggestion: Try to get hold of a math student and explain your problem to her using a little figure, etc.

Comment: I don't think I'm using any special terms... To reduce the question: I have a direction vector. I want a pitch and yaw in degrees. How do I get them?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $d$ is the starting direction vector of the machine. Then, $d$ is also the axis of roll rotation. Suppose $y$ is the axis of pitch rotation and suppose we want to end with direction vector that is pointing the same way as direction $v$. If we apply the roll rotation the axis of pitch rotation rotates also.

We will first roll by an angle $\theta$ until the axis of pitch rotation moves to the position perpendicular to $d$ and $v$. We will then pitch by an angle $\phi$. Thus, $\phi$ can be deduced as the angle between $d$ and $v$:
$$ \phi = \arccos \left( \frac{d\cdot v}{\Vert d \Vert \Vert v \Vert} \right) $$

$\theta$ seems more problematic to discover. In order to apply the pitch we want to have the pitch axes in the direction of the vector $ d \times v $. The angle $$\psi = \arccos \left( \frac{(d \times v)\cdot y}{\Vert d \times v \Vert \Vert y \Vert} \right) $$ is the smallest angle between $y$ and $ d \times v $. The right roll angle $\theta$ is thus either $\psi$ or $\psi+\pi$:
$$ \theta=\begin{cases}
0, & \mbox{if }y\cdot\left(d\times v\right)=\Vert y\Vert\,\Vert d\times v\Vert,\\
\psi, & \mbox{if }\left(y\times\left(d\times v\right)\right)\cdot d\geq 0,\\
\psi+\pi, & \mbox{if }\left(y\times\left(d\times v\right)\right)\cdot d<0.
\end{cases} $$
The angle $\theta$ was set to zero when $y$ is already in the direction of $d\times v$.

It is important that these two rotations are applied as follows: first the roll by the angle $\theta$ and second the pitch with the angle $\phi$.

There are also other combinations of roll, pitch and yaw that can result in the same maneuver.

Comment: I'm working on trying to test this method, but I'm running into some implementation-related issues. It also seems awfully clunky; surely there's a way to work out the needed angle direction without having to move the machine around?

Comment: I tried to explain it by editing the answer.